# Collision detection between different certain elements to increase/deduct score in a HTML/CSS/Javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a small drag and drop trash sorting item where trash items fall from the sky and needs to be sorted in their respective trash bins (General, Glass, Plastic, Paper, Organic & Metal). I have made the collision between the trash items and the trash bin with the score increment. But the score increases whenever any trash is collided with a trash bin and deleted. I cannot seem to figure to restrict certain trash items to certain trash bins (ex - if newspaper collides and get deleted by touching paper bin then the score will increase by 100 point other if newspaper touches any other bin or any other items touches paper bin 50 points are decreased).

```
import Assets from "./utils/assets.js";
import Sprites from "./components/Sprites.js";

const canvas = document.getElementById("base_layer");
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let score = 0
const scoreEl = document.querySelector('#scoreEl');
const modalEl = document.querySelector('#modalEl');
const modalScoreEl = document.querySelector('#modalScoreEl');

const bgCanvas = document.getElementById("bg_layer");
bgCanvas.width = innerWidth
bgCanvas.height = innerHeight

const bgContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

const buttonEl = document.getElementById('#buttonEl')


// STORING ASSETS AS AN ARRAY
const assetsList = [
  {
    name: "background",
    url: "./assets/background/bg_stage_3.jpeg",
  },

  //BINS
  {
    name: "general_bin",
    url: "./assets/bins/general_bin.png",
  },
  {
    name: "glass_bin",
    url: "./assets/bins/glass_bin.png",
  },
  {
    name: "metal_bin",
    url: "./assets/bins/metal_bin.png",
  },
  {
    name: "organic_bin",
    url: "./assets/bins/organic_bin.png",
  },
  {
    name: "paper_bin",
    url: "./assets/bins/paper_bin.png",
  },
  {
    name: "plastic_bin",
    url: "./assets/bins/plastic_bin.png",
  },

  // GENERAL WASTE
  {
    name: "black_bag",
    url: "./assets/general/blackbag_1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "coffee_cup",
    url: "./assets/general/coffee_1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "red_cup",
    url: "./assets/general/redcup_1.png",
  },

  // GLASS WASTE
  {
    name: "glass_bottle",
    url: "./assets/glass/glassbottle_1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "wine_glass",
    url: "./assets/glass/wineglass_1.png",
  },


  // METAL WASTE
  {
    name: "soda_can_1",
    url: "./assets/metal/soda_can_1.png",
  },


  // ORGANIC WASTE
  {
    name: "apple_1",
    url: "./assets/organic/apple_1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "banana_1",
    url: "./assets/organic/banana_1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "egg_shell",
    url: "./assets/organic/eggshell_1.png",
  },


  // PAPER WASTE
  {
    name: "box_1",
    url: "./assets/paper/box_1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "newspaper_1",
    url: "./assets/paper/newspaper_1.png",
  },

  // PLASTIC WASTE
  {
    name: "plastic_bottle",
    url: "./assets/plastic/plasticbottle_1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "plastic_milk",
    url: "./assets/plastic/plastic_milk_1.png",
  },
  {
    name: "plastic_bag",
    url: "./assets/plastic/plastic_bag_1.png",
  },
];


let background,
  trash = [],
  bins = [],
  lastAnimationFrameTime = 0,
  elapsed;

const assets = new Assets().loadImages(assetsList);


let animationId
function startGame() {
  draw();
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function animate(now) {
  let trashEl = trash[0];

  elapsed = (now - lastAnimationFrameTime) / 450;
  
  //sprite collision
  bins.forEach((bin) => {
    if (trashEl.isCollide(bin)) {

      if(bin.width < 110) {
       bin.width += 0.5;
       bin.height += 0.5;
      }

      if(trashEl.y + trashEl.height > bin.y + 30 && !trashEl.isHeld) {
        trashEl.isDeleted = true;
        score += 100
        scoreEl.innerHTML = score;
      }
      
    } else {
      if (bin.width > 100) {
        bin.width -= 0.5;
        bin.height -= 0.5;
        
      }
    }
  });

  // TO ADD WHEN THE GAME ENDS 
  modalEl.style.display = "block"
  modalScoreEl.innerHTML = score

  // FREEZE FRAME WHEN GAME ENDS
  // cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);

  // clear the canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // updates
  if (!trashEl.isHeld) {
    trashEl.y += 80 * elapsed;
  }

  if (trashEl.y > canvas.height) {
    trash = [];
    randomTrash()
  }

  // draw();
  background.draw(bgContext);
  bins.forEach((bin) => bin.draw(context));
  
  if (trashEl.isDeleted && !trashEl.isHeld) {
    trash = [];
    randomTrash();
  } else {
    trashEl.draw(context);
  }

  lastAnimationFrameTime = now;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function draw() {
  assets.gameAssets.forEach((asset) => {
    if (asset.name === "box_1") {
      drawTrash(asset.image);
    }
    if (asset.name === "background") {
      drawBackground(asset.image);
    } else {
      drawBins(asset);
    }
  });
}


function randomTrash() {
  const nonTrashAssets = assets.gameAssets.filter(asset => {
    return asset.name !== "general_bin" && asset.name !== "glass_bin" && asset.name !== "metal_bin" && asset.name !== "organic_bin" && asset.name !== "paper_bin" && asset.name !== "plastic_bin" && asset.name !== "background" ;
  });
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * nonTrashAssets.length);
  const {image} = nonTrashAssets[randomIndex];
  drawTrash(image);
}


function drawTrash(image) {
  let randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width - 250 - 125) + 125); 
  trash.push(new Sprites(image, randomX, -50, 50, 50).draw(context));
}


function drawBackground(image) {
  background = new Sprites(image, 0, 0, bgCanvas.width, bgCanvas.height).draw(
    bgContext
  );
}

function drawBins({name, image}) {
  if (name === "general_bin") {
    bins.push(
      new Sprites(
        image,
        canvas.width * 0.,
        canvas.height - 105,
        100,
        140
      ).draw(context)
    );
  } else if (name === "glass_bin") {
    bins.push(
      new Sprites(
        image,
        canvas.width * 0.23,
        canvas.height - 105,
        100,
        140
      ).draw(context)
    );
  } else if (name === "metal_bin") {
    bins.push(
      new Sprites(
        image,
        canvas.width * 0.45,
        canvas.height - 105,
        100,
        140
      ).draw(context)
    );
    } else if (name === "organic_bin") {
      bins.push(
        new Sprites(
          image,
          canvas.width * 0.63,
          canvas.height - 105,
          100,
          140
        ).draw(context)
      );
    } else if (name === "paper_bin") {
      bins.push(
        new Sprites(
          image,
          canvas.width * 0.43,
          canvas.height - 105,
          100,
          140
          ).draw(context)
          );
  } else if (name === "plastic_bin") {
    bins.push(
      new Sprites(
        image,
        canvas.width * 0.935,
        canvas.height - 105,
        100,
        140
      ).draw(context)
    );
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", startGame);

canvas.addEventListener("pointerdown", initDrag);
canvas.addEventListener("pointermove", dragging);
canvas.addEventListener("pointerup", stopDragging);
canvas.addEventListener("pointerleave", stopDragging);

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  init()
})

function initDrag({offsetX, offsetY}) {
  let trashEl = trash[0];

  trashEl.isDragged(offsetX, offsetY);
}

function dragging({offsetX, offsetY}) {
  let trashEl = trash[0];

  if (trashEl.isHeld) {
    trashEl.x = offsetX;
    trashEl.y = offsetY;
  }
}

function stopDragging(e) {
  let trashEl = trash[0];

  trashEl.isHeld = false;
}
```

I tried to restrict it like this

```
if trash === "paper_bin" &&& (trashEl === "newspaper_1" || trashEl === "box_1")
```

But nothing really happens instead when I implement this change then the score just decreases by 50 no matter what touches what.